# How can i Add selected text from element into CSV file using selenium, robot framework without using python

Tags: selenium, robotframework

I am now create an automation Project using Selenium, Robotframework and maven3.0 in Intellij IDEA Environment.

I'm trying to get text from web element and store that into csv file. I get the text successfully but i don't know how to insert the text into csv file.

I set the first row as Header. I want to add that value below `Column Name="Leave_Request_Number"`

My Existing code is

```
  ${value}            Get Text        ${Get_Request_Number}
  ${substringvalue}   Get Substring   ${value}  66  76
  Append CSV Line     Leave_Request_Number  ${substringvalue}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45137586/how-to-append-data-to-csv-file-in-robot-framework

Comment: Sir That is also my Comment. But Nobody reply my question so i ask as individual

Comment: To us `Append CSV Line` you need to use 2 lists.

Comment: Sorry Sir I didn't get you

Comment: Selected value is "Request has been generated successfully with the Request Number : LEV-001153" but i want only add last 10 digits(LEV-001153) into the Csv Line.I get that Request Number but can't store in csv line header="Leave_Request_Number"

Comment: What is the csv library that you use? Googling the keyword "Append CSV Line" returns literally only this page.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to append data to csv file in Robot Framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45137586/how-to-append-data-to-csv-file-in-robot-framework)

Answer (score 1):

`Append to CSV File` Requires a list of lists, you can do something like

```
*** Test Cases ***
test

  ${value}            Get Text        ${Get_Request_Number}
  ${substringvalue}   Get Substring   ${value}  66  76 
  ${list}=    Create List    ${substringvalue}
  ${data}=    create list    ${list}
  Append To Csv File    ${file_path}  ${data}
```

Comment: Sir, It Shows an Error like Append To Csv File is Not a Keyword

Comment: Error:- No keyword with name 'Append To Csv File' found. Did you mean: OperatingSystem.Append To File

Comment: And also how to add value into specific column?

Comment: You need to install the Robot Framework CSVLibrary. You can do this by  `pip install -U robotframework-csvlibrary`. Then use `Library   CSVLibrary` in the `***Settings***`

Comment: Sir i didn't using python

Comment: @SARAVANANPONNUSAMY "Sir i didn't using python" Robot framework is implemented in python, hence you are "using python" you need to install the CSVLibrary as @KeithMc18 stated in order to use the `Append to CSV File` Keyword.